Regex to replace all characters except first 3 chars
I have a requirement as part of which i need to replace all the alphanumeric chars in a string except first 3 chars with X.
Example:

123 wer --> 123 XXX
hello@gmail.com --> helXX@XXXXX.XXX

I tried to come up with regex (

Regex --> (?<=^...)(.*)

) that does match all chars except first 3 but it replaces rest characters with single X like below:

123 wer --> 123X
hello@gmail.com --> helX

Can someone please guide on the right regex to use?

You may use this regex for matching:
(?<=.{3})([^\p{L}\d\n]*)[\p{L}\d]

and replace it with:
$1X

RegEx Demo
RegEx Details:

(?<=.{3}): Assert that we have at least 3 characters on left of the current position. This condition is meant to leave first 3 characters from replacement as it will always be true for all the position after 3rd.
([^\p{L}\d\n]*): Match 0 or more of any characters that are not alphanumeric and line break. Capture this substring in group #1
[\p{L}\d]: Match any alphanumeric (including unicode letters)
Replacement is $1X that puts back captured value from group #1 followed by letter X


You could replace matches of
(?<=.{3})[\dA-Za-z]

with 'X'.
Demo
The expression reads, "match each alphanumeric character that is preceded by three (or more) characters", (?<=.{3}) being a positive lookbehind.
